# Java 8 default implementation is not available when instance is passed as its superinterface

Tags: java, java-8

I receive a `AbstractMethodError` when invoking a method that, I think, should have a default implementation in the target instance.

I create a functional interface in three parameters but also derive from `java.util.function.Function` and provide a default implementation of `Function#apply(..)`. I then create an instance of my interface using a 3-parameter lambda expression. Both the 3-argument method and `Function#apply(..)` work just fine in the created instance.

When I pass the created instance to a method expecting my interface, I can invoke `Function#apply(..)` from within the method and it works fine.

But when I pass the instance to a method that is expecting a `Function`, I receive the `AbstractMethodError` when I try to invoke `Function#apply(..)`.

It seems I am missing an understanding of how and when default methods are bound to an instance. What am I doing incorrectly?

To demonstrate:

```
package spike;

import java.util.function.BiFunction;
import java.util.function.Function;

public class ReductionProblem {

    interface F3<T, U, V, R> extends Function<T, BiFunction<U, V, R>> {

        default BiFunction<U, V, R> apply(final T t) {
            return (U u, V v) -> apply(t, u, v);
        }

        R apply(T t, U u, V v);

    }

    private static <T, U, V, R> BiFunction<U, V, R> workingReduce(
            F3<T, U, V, R> f, T t) {
        return f.apply(t);
    }

    private static <T, U, V, R> BiFunction<U, V, R> brokenReduce(
            Function<T, BiFunction<U, V, R>> f, T t) {
        return f.apply(t);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        /*
         * Object is instantiated here, right? So, Function#apply(Integer)
         * should be defined and ready to go.
         */
        final F3<Integer, Integer, String, Integer> f3 = (a, b, c) -> a * b
                * c.length();

        final Integer a = 3, b = 13;
        final String c = "see";

        final Integer expected = a * b * c.length();

        Integer v1 = f3.apply(a, b, c);
        display("invoke with 3", expected, v1);

        /*
         * It appears that f3 can indeed behave as a Function<Integer,
         * BiFunction<>> ...
         */
        Integer v2 = f3.apply(a).apply(b, c);
        display("invoke with 1 then 2", expected, v2);

        /*
         * From inside a method, no problem...
         */
        Integer v3 = workingReduce(f3, a).apply(b, c);
        display("invoke with 1 inside special reducer", expected, v3);

        /*
         * But when passed explicitly as a Function, AbstractMethodError is
         * thrown from inside the reduction method. So, it seems that the
         * instantiation of the object with the default method implementation
         * does not occur where I am supposing it does.
         */
        Integer v4 = brokenReduce(f3, a).apply(b, c);
        display("invoke with 1 inside general reducer", expected, v4);

    }

    private static void display(String label, Object expected, Object actual) {

        System.out.println(label + ":"
                + (actual.equals(expected) ? "pass" : "fail"));

    }

}
```

Comment: What compiler are you using?

Comment: @SotiriosDelimanolis Oracle javac 1.8.0_05 for Linux

Comment: It works for me. Are you sure you aren't compiling in an IDE? I've only been able to reproduce it in Eclipse.

Comment: @SotiriosDelimanolis D'oh. Yes, I am using Eclipse and forgetting it doesn't use javac. So this is an Eclipse compiler problem it seems.

Comment: Funny, I have already found a couple of other bugs in the Eclipse Java 8 compiler but didn't think to check if that was the case here. I was sure I just didn't understand the language semantics in this case.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This seems like a bug in whatever compiler you are using. I was only able to reproduce it with the Eclipse compiler. It works fine with

```
[~/workspace/Example/bin]$ javac -version
javac 1.8.0_05
[~/workspace/Example/bin]$
```

The error here seems to be that the compiler doesn't add an `invokeinterface` for invoking the method but instead references the abstract method itself. Or maybe it builds the instance resulting from the lambda without the `default` method implementation, but that doesn't seem likely since other invocations work.

Comment: This Eclipse bug report filed 6/2 seems to be describing the same problem: https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=436350